# Exibir videos em tag <video> usando angularjs

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

View:

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="x in content.spells">
....
    <video width="320" height="240" ng-src="{{(getIdVideo(content.id) | trusted )}}"   controls>
          Seu navegador não suporta o elemento <code>video</code>.
    </video>
....
</div>
```

Controlller:

```
  $scope.getIdVideo = function(videoId){
    videoId = videoId.toString();
    for (var i=0; i<=4; i++){
      if (videoId.length != 4){
        //videoId = videoId.push('0');
        videoId = "0"+videoId;
      }

    }

    return 'http://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/champion-abilities/videos/mp4/'+videoId+'_02.mp4';
  };
```

Chamo essa função `getIdVideo()` para me retornar um video de acordo com o id passado como argumento, o problema é que para cada id preciso mostrar 4 videos
variando, de 2 a 5, o numero que vem após o "_" da url abaixo:

"http:/cdn.leagueoflegends.com/champion-abilities/videos/mp4/'+videoId+'_02.mp4"

Pensei em usar fazer com que a função retorne as 4 url's e então usar um `ng-repeat` para exibir os 4 videos diferentes, mas não consegui implementar isto. De que maneira posso resolver meu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Já que é uma quantidade fixa de vídeos (e isso não for mudar).

Podes simplesmente fazer o seguinte:

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="x in content.spells">
     <video width="320" height="240" ng-src="{{(getIdVideo(content.id, '02') | trusted )}}"   controls>
           Seu navegador não suporta o elemento <code>video</code>.
     </video>

     <video width="320" height="240" ng-src="{{(getIdVideo(content.id, '03') | trusted )}}"   controls>
           Seu navegador não suporta o elemento <code>video</code>.
     </video>

     <video width="320" height="240" ng-src="{{(getIdVideo(content.id, '04') | trusted )}}"   controls>
           Seu navegador não suporta o elemento <code>video</code>.
     </video>

     <video width="320" height="240" ng-src="{{(getIdVideo(content.id, '05') | trusted )}}"   controls>
           Seu navegador não suporta o elemento <code>video</code>.
     </video>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getIdVideo = function(videoId, seq){
videoId = videoId.toString();
for (var i=0; i<=4; i++){
  if (videoId.length != 4){
    //videoId = videoId.push('0');
    videoId = "0"+videoId;
  }

}

return 'http://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/champion-abilities/videos/mp4/' + videoId + '_' + seq + '.mp4';
```

};

Comment: Usando seu código consegui os videos, mas tá sendo exibido uns 12 videos(repetidos de 3 em 3) , acho que por causa do ng-repeat da tag div. Se eu retornar um array com as 4 url's ao invés de apenas uma por vez e depois usar um ng-repeat na tag video para percorrer as url's resolve? Até consigo implementar isso na função, mas não sei como fazer na view.

Comment: Se está retornando 12 vídeos no código acima, com um ng-repeat na tag <video> para 4 urls vai acontecer o mesma coisas. 

Ta retornando 12 videos porque existe 3 elementos dentro do seu array "spells". Se for esse o caso, está correto retornar os 12 vídeos, não? Não sei se entendi bem o que você pretende fazer. Posta aqui o conteúdo do "content.spells" e explica com um pouco mais de detalhes o que você precisa.